Could I straighten the fingers to shape the palm into a flat position using Blender's or any other's software?
I have a 3D scan of a human's left palm. However, the fingers are rolled in/not straightened. I need to 3D print an imprint of a human's palm, but it needs to be flat for it.

you can try to open the hand with the Pose brush in Sculpt mode, not sure the result will be ok, it depends on your mesh

You should post a few images of what you're working with and/or images of what you're aiming for, and if necessary share your blendfile to give us the most info to work with to help solve your question.

If the scan is of a closed hand you are not going to be able to repose it like that. There's presumably nothing inside the fingers. Fixing that would likely be more work than making a hand from scratch

Also 3d scans are notoriously hard to edit and reason with

Gentlemen, thank you very much!
